# Lua Convert string into more arrays

Tags: lua

I need a way to convert this string `"foo/bar/test/hello"` into this

```
foo = {
  bar = {
    test = {
      hello = {},
    },
  },
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `string.gmatch` to split it, then just build the table you want, try this:

```
local pprint = require('pprint')

example="foo/bar/test/hello"
v={}
s=v
for i in string.gmatch(example, "(%w+)") do
    v[i]={}
    v=v[i]
end

pprint(s)
```

PS. in order print table, i use [pprint](https://github.com/jagt/pprint.lua) here .

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is the natural tool to use. Here is one solution. For simplicity, `convert` returns a table.

```
S="foo/bar/test/hello"

function convert(s)
    local a,b=s:match("^(.-)/(.-)$")
    local t={}
    if a==nil then
        a=s
        t[a]={}
    else
        t[a]=convert(b)
    end
    return t
end

function dump(t,n)
    for k,v in pairs(t) do
        print(string.rep("\t",n)..k,v)
        dump(v,n+1)
    end
end

z=convert(S)
dump(z,0)
```

If you really need to set a global variable `foo`, then do this at the end:

```
k,v=next(z); _G[k]=v
print(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another (non-recursive) possibility:

```
function show(s)
  local level = 0
  for s in s:gmatch '[^/]+' do
    io.write('\n',(' '):rep(level) .. s .. ' = {')
    level = level + 2
  end
  for level = level-2, 0, -2 do
    io.write('}',level > 0 and ',\n' or '\n',(' '):rep(level-2))
  end
end

show 'foo/bar/test/hello'
```